# Spring Security , Spring Boot and ContextLoaderListener

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

When we add spring securityfilter using `web.xml` , following is the declaration

```
<filter>
      <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
      <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
```

and we also must have

```
<listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>      
</listener>
```

My question  is :
Why do we need to define `ContextLoaderListener` (I know it creates a `ROOT application context` and `DispatcherServlet` creates `child application context`)
when we declare `springSecurityFilterChain` ?

My understanding is  :

1)Behind the scenes ,  `DelegatingFilterProxy` will delegate to a bean called "`springSecurityFilterChain`"  (value of `filter-name` attribute)

2)Is this bean (`springSecurityFilterChain`) and (`FilterChainProxyBean` which ultimately routes request to different filters in spring security ) gets created when 
  `ROOT application Context` is created , since `ContextLoaderListener` creates a `ROOT application context` ? and hence we need `ContextLoaderListener` ?

If that is the case , how spring boot handles spring security ? 
Because spring boot just requires addition of spring security dependency in `pom.xml` and everything works fine  like below -

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Behind the scenes spring boot creates `DispatcherServlet` when `spring-boot-starter-web` is added in classpath. 
So how is spring security works here without `ContextLoaderListener` ?

Comment: The `DelegatingFilterProxy` will delegate to beans, by default, defined in the ROOT application context. It will NOT delegate to beans in one of the child contexts ( you could have multiple `DispatcherServlet`s or other servlets using Spring). In a regular application the ROOT context is loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener`. The ROOT context is basically nothing more then the `ApplicationContext` stored in a well known location. The key here is ROOT context. Spring Boot still makes sure that the ROOT context is available.

Comment: Thanks Deinum. How does spring boot makes sure that ROOT application context is available ?

Comment: The ROOT context is either an `ApplicationContext` registered at a well known location. To be exact in the `ServletContext` under the a well known name from the [`WebApplicationContext`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/WebApplicationContext.html#ROOT_WEB_APPLICATION_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTE). As a fallback, see the code of the `DelegatingFilterProxy` it will check the `ServletContext` for a single `ApplicationContext` if that is found that will be used as the ROOT context.